# How can I install python API LGSVL?

Tags: python, api, installation, simulator

I want to work on LGSVL simulator. Downloaded Simulator. But couldn't find a way to install its python api. 
found API files at:
https://github.com/lgsvl/PythonAPI
and documentation at: 
https://www.lgsvlsimulator.com/docs/python-api/
They have just written 
'''
pip3 install --user -e 
'''

How can I use pip for installing this API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you do the git clone or download and unzip the package, cd into the **PythonAPI** directory.  Make sure that the *setup.py* is present. The setup.py file contains the information needed to install the package. Next, enter in the pip install command followed by a period.  The *period* indicates the current working directory.

```
pip3 install --user -e .
```

Hope that helps!